# UAD2 Plug-ins - Have you used them?

Tags: plug-ins

Have any of you used [these plug-ins?](http://www.uaudio.com/uad-plug-ins.html?utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=satellite&utm_content=mixonline&utm_source=mixonline)

How do they sound?

I'm demoing them now but I would like to see what you guys think of them if you've used them.

Answer (score 1):

I Personally love the UADplug-ins.  When I was apprenticing, the studio I was at used them regularly in our mixes.  The Neve's 1081 and 1073 EQ's where almost always used.  The DreamVerb and EMT 180 again where almost always used.  My personal favorite is the Roland RE-201, ALOT of fun to play with. They have plug-ins that emulate old school hardware, like the Fairchild 670, as well.

I think they sound great, but I think they're focused for 'sound design' in a musical realm.  Are you composing?

Answer (score 1):

I have had the luck of working in several large, analog rooms stacked with some incredible outboard gear. Many of which now appear as emulations in UAD. 
As plugins started coming out, many, many developers would claim to have *finally* made a faithful recreation of, say, the Urei 1176LN. I tried all of them, because I really didn't want to face mixing drums without one. They all sucked. 
The moment I tried the UAD version, I was sold. It almost exactly recreates everything you expect from the 1176LN—even the noise!
Same goes for all the plugins I've chosen to purchase: The LA-2A, the Pultec EQs, the SSL bus compressor... have all sounded more or less exactly as I remembered the originals sounding. 
And the others: Fairchild 670; Roland Dimension D, Plate 140; Heliios EQ—though I never used the originals—sound so good that I can only assume that they hit the nail on the head on those as well!
Though any powered card like this is going to introduce latency, UAD has minimised this to the degree that I can actually track with a couple UAD plugs on the input (if I wanted to).

I whole-heartedly recommend this plugin system to anyone.

Go ahead and [listen to some mixes](http://thedemoking.com/?p=605) done with plenty of UAD plugs:

Answer (score 0):

What accelerator card are you using?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I forgot about this question. HD Accel and a Core card.